# How can I add and keep synced my gmail contacts in evolution?

Tags: evolution, gmail, contacts

There is not much more to say. I'd like to be able to see my gmail contacts in the contacts section of Evolution. I'm going to change them only from gmail, so a read-only solution will work.

What I really want is to be able to access my Android phone-book (stored on gmail) without retrieving my cellular from my pockets. Yes, I'm that lazy.

Comment: OK... I'm stupid. It's pretty obvious. Well, easy rep pick from some one providing a quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use the gmail web client.

Or you can go into evolution and add your google account as an address book:

[image: shows add google address book]

Comment: I don't use gmail (for mail) and have an evolution windows always at glance in my secondary monitor. So it's much more convenient. Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps Apparently this doesn't work in evolution anymore. :-(